# how to close bufferedwriters?

Tags: java, io

This code is taken from the oracle java tutorial.
Why does it use an if statement with the condition
(writer != null) to decide whether or not to close
the writer?

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
String s = ...;
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, charset);
    writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
} finally {
    if (writer != null) writer.close();//******************************************
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because if the writer is null, its already closed. As its within a finally block, its always going to be the last thing called, so to make sure that the writer closed correctly you check that it isn't already done further up in the code, and if not (writer != null) close it off.

Answer (score 0):

if the `new BufferedWriter` threw an exception then `writer` would be `null`, so trying to close it would give a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Java 7 autoclosing

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, charset)) {
   ...
}
```